# conditionally make different url from controller name in MVC by appending word to controller name

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller called ExpenseController. So the url becomes www.website.com/Expense/ViewName

How do I make the url be instead "www.website.com/HPQExpense/ViewName" without changing controller and folder name?

I want to append "HPQ" to all the controllers based on certain condition. So if condition is true url will be like "www.website.com/HPQExpense/ViewName" else it will be "www.website.com/QBLExpense/ViewName".

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have multiple controllers or you just want to display different name?

Comment: I just want to display different name in Url for same controller